# How do I get the value of an Infopath lookup field using Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, infopath

On my SharePoint page, I have an Infopath form with a few lookup fields. I've used the code below (with and without the hash) to try and get the value of the field, but when I put the value into an alert, it simply comes back as 'undefined'. The IE debugger shows no errors, so I can't properly debug it and am relying on trial and error.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
var v = $("#ctl00_ctl33_g_2ba23d46_fa1c_45ee_9443_16f4a016f5d2_FormControl1_V1_I1_S1_I1_D1").val();
```

I have also tried the following, but I'm not surprised this didn't work as it looks like it's looking for a textbox value.

```
$("input:text[originalid='V1_I1_S1_I1_D1']").val()
```

Rendered page HTML is here - http://pastebin.com/wG96ZEUn

Comment: Can you post your html please

Comment: @Ryad.iv edited the post to include the HTML

Comment: the rendered page please

Comment: @Ryad.iv sorry, what do you mean the rendered page? as in a screenshot of the page? or the full HTML?

Comment: When looking at the InfoPath form in your web browser, the HTML that is displayed (right click -> View Source, or you can use the F12 developer tools to inspect the HTML)

Comment: @Thriggle ohh, no problem - added a pastebin link to the HTML copied from View Source

Comment: where did you get the `ctl00_ctl33_g_2ba23d46_fa1c_45ee_9443_16f4a016f5d2_FormControl1_V1_I1_S1_I1_D1` id from? Didn't find it in your page.

Comment: @Breno F12, highlighted the select box on the form and it had the ID in there

Comment: @Breno sorry, I've uploaded a new paste - it should be in there

Comment: A tip, write some bad code that will throw an error. In your debugger is should show you what line the error is on. Then you can find your code section that is having issues and break point it.